# getting error while accessing the same code for get pixel value

Tags: python, opencv, pixel

I am trying to read RGB pixels from a `numpy ndarray` type image. I implemented it in 2 class files. To search for histograms and look for momen. The first process will go through a histogram search first (calling the `class histogram`), then the process continues by searching for the momen (calling the `class momen`). In both of these classes there is each process of reading the RGB pixels of the input image. I access RGB pixels using the following code:

```
def getbyte(self, gambar):
    for i in range(0,gambar.shape[0]):
        for j in range(0,gambar.shape[1]):
            self.p.append(gambar[i,j])
    self.flat = [i for sets in self.p for i in sets]
    
    return self.flat
```

Then I run the program. If you see from the flow process, then the histogram will be processed before momen. When I run, when I look at the `console` (I use `spyder IDE`), the process has arrived at the momen search line, it indicates that the histogram search has succeeded, right?

Now then what I want to ask, when searching for moments is executed, I get an error in the reading of the RGB pixel of the image, as follows:

```
self.flat = [i for sets in self.pMoment for i in sets]
```

`TypeError: 'numpy.uint8' object is not iterable`

Strangely, when searching for a histogram with the exact pixel capture code, the error does not appear. But why when searching for the momen this code has a problem and an error appears? What error is that?

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming the `self.p` attribute is a list (my assumption is based on the`append ()`method used) then the error code is in the loop adding a value to the `self.p` attribute. Supposedly, before flattening, attribute self.p should be a list of list. However, in the code self.p is still a list of ints.

So what needs to be done is to temporarily store the pixel values ​​in the image in each row using the new variables. Then this variable will be added (`append`) to `self.p`.

The code snippet will look like this:

```
def getbyte (self, image):
    for i in range (0, image.shape [0]):
        rowPixel = []
        for j in range (0, images.shape [1]):
            rowPixel.append (image [i, j])
        self.p.append (rowPixel)
    self.flat = [i for sets in p for i in sets]
    return self.flat
```

I have tried the code above using a 2-dimensional image variable of type `np.ndarray`. Because of my assumption you are doing 2 nested loops.